# How do you find out Glory's backstory in Shadowrun Returns Dragonfall?

Tags: shadowrun-returns, shadowrun-dragonfall

I just finished Shadowrun Returns: Dragonfall (awesome game). I heard Glory has an interesting backstory, but I didn't see any of it (she left to take care of her own business at the end). How do I access it in the game -- do I have to talk to someone specific or do a quest a certain way?

Comment: Better question: how does Glory pick her nose? (You're welcome: I had to keep myself from asking how she wipes also...)

Comment: Wine bottle corks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

She does indeed. Just make sure you talk to her (and the other characters) after each mission.